# Including HTML code with CSS in php function

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to write a PHP function, inside it, I am writing HTML code.

The problem is I am unable to link CSS file to the HTML code.

```
function foo() {
    // ---do some php stuff---
    echo '
    <html>
        <head>
           <link href="bar.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        </head>
        <body
             ---some code---
        </body>
    </html>';
}
```

What should be the correct approach?

Comment: The *correct approach* would be, not to put your HTML in functions.

Comment: Are you sure, that path to css file is correct?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone how should I achieve what I am trying to do.

Comment: @Stranger yes the path is correct

Comment: what is the source HTML output that you get when you run this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function foo() {
// ---do some php stuff---

$link_address = 'correct-path-for-css-file-from-root-folder/bar.css';

echo '
<html>
    <head>
       <link href="' . $link_address . '" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </head>
    <body
         ---some code---
    </body>
</html>';
```

}

I think this is working.try this.

Comment: Now I have landed into one more problem, I want to use php tags again inside HTML. something like this
<li><input type="text" placeholder="<?php echo $fz_variable?>"></li>
How do I achieve that?

Comment: Here I have added answer for your other question.Try it.

<?php echo '<li><input type="text" placeholder="';?>
<?php echo '$fz_variable';?>
<?php echo '?>"></li>';?>

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
<style>
 .classname {
 padding: etc;
 margin: etc;
 }
</style>

echo "<div class='classname'>text here</div>";
```